# Unity3d do something when attached a script to gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My problem is, when I attached my script to a game object, I want to make some calculation and add Edge Collider to this game object. Is there any event like "OnAttached" or something else?

Thanks for all your helps.

> Thanks to Ruben I found the solution. RequireComponent is what I was looking for, but I actually needed an event like "OnAttached" and at last I found. It is "void Reset()".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The automated addition of the Edge Collider can be done by using `[RequireComponent(typeof(EdgeCollider))]`

Learn more here:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RequireComponent.html

**Edit:** OP says this wasn't helpful, refer to his comment below for more information:

You then can simply put all necessary calculations into the Start() functions, which get called, when a script is enabled.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! so may I make calculations after added EdgeCollider and edit it?

Comment: Sorry, forgot that part. The basic Start() function should be the right place for that!

Comment: Thanks a lot for RequireComponent answer, but Start function is not what I need :)

Comment: I found the solution btw. [InitializeOnLoad] attribute for classes or [InitializeOnLoadMethod] attribute for methods work very well for my purpose.

Comment: I'm currently not on a PC with unity, sorry for the misinformation. I added an edit in my answer to refer to the additional information you provided.

Comment: I had to made a little more research because [InitializeOnLoadMethod] attribute didn't helped just as I wanted. And at last I found solution :) 
void Reset() function is called when user Reset component or add it first time. 

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Reset.html